# Overload COM class methods with methods from a standard module using VTable hacking

Tags: vba, com, 64-bit, vtable, iunknown

Quick question - I've just been testing overwriting methods of a class by changing entries in its VTable using low level copy memory api.

### Background

I've had some success, and can swap 2 entries in the VTable of a class if they have the same signature. So a class definition like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Meow()
    Debug.Print "Meow"
End Sub

Public Sub Woof()
    Debug.Print "Woof"
End Sub
```

... generates a VTable like this:

[image: VTable]

... and I can swap the entries at positions 7 and 8 to make `cls.Meow` print `Woof` and vice-versa. I can also swap the entry from the VTable of one class with the VTable of an entirely different one (provided I don't try to dereference the implicit `this` pointer by calling `Me.anything`)

So I can make another class

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Tweet()
    Debug.Print "Tweet"
End Sub
```

and swap the behaviour of `Woof` from one with `Tweet` from the other. Not too complicated, I can share the code if people need it.

### What I can't do...

... however, is figure out how to **swap a class method with a method from a standard module?**

Based on [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/learn-about-vbs-class-method-sleight-of-hand/) article, it appears that the COM machinery which VBA is built on requires 2 things of class methods which VBA hides:

- They have an implicit `this` pointer
- They return an HRESULT (`typedef long`)

So I thought

```
Public Sub Meow()
```

in a class module `Class1` is equivalent to

```
Public Function Meow(ByVal this As LongPtr) As Long
```

I've also tried

```
Public Function Meow(ByRef meObj As Class1) As Long
Public Function Meow(ByRef meObj As Class1) As LongPtr 'but HResult is 32 bit int
Public Sub Meow(ByVal this As LongPtr)
```

etc. But VBA always crashes when I try to invoke the method from the VTable. So I'm at a bit of a loss. I wonder if things are different on a 64 bit computer, or if the standard module functions do something weird to the calling stack. The thing is I've seen [examples of code](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?854963-VB6-IEnumVARIANT-For-Each-support-without-a-typelib) where the entire VTable is assembled from standard module functions, so I know it's possible but just not sure how to convert the signatures correctly

How can I overwrite a VTable entry with a method defined in a standard module?

Comment: The behavior is exactly the same on x64. However, you are able to 'redirect' the IUnknown and the IDispatch methods to a Function inside a .bas module (as well as the IEnumVariant methods in your linked example). I assume these work because they are not VB. I think you cannot redirect a VB class method because of the way VB classes work. Consider the ```Me``` keyword (which behaves like a function/property get). You couldn't possibly replicate the ```Me``` behaviour in a .bas module. There must be more things happening behind the scenes. Maybe the calling convention is also different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was only partially corect in my comment on your question. I still believe that the `Me` keyword plays a role in preventing the 'redirection' of a class method to a method inside a standard .bas module. But that is only applicable to early binding.

IDispatch::Invoke can actually call a method inside a .bas module with no problem. Your initial method signature was correct:

> ```
> Public Function Meow(ByRef meObj As Class1) As Long
> ```

`Class1` code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Meow()
    Debug.Print "Meow"
End Sub

Public Sub Woof()
    Debug.Print "Woof"
End Sub
```

Code in a standard .bas module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim c As Object 'Must be late-binded!
    Dim vTblPtr As LongPtr
    Dim vTblMeowPtr As LongPtr
    Dim originalMeow As LongPtr
    '
    Set c = New Class1
    c.Meow 'Prints "Meow" to the Immediate Window
    '
    'The address of the virtual table
    vTblPtr = MemLongPtr(ObjPtr(c))
    '
    'The address of the Class1.Meow method within the virtual table
    vTblMeowPtr = vTblPtr + 7 * PTR_SIZE
    '
    'The current address of the Class1.Meow method
    originalMeow = MemLongPtr(vTblMeowPtr)
    '
    'Replace the address of Meow with the one in a .bas module
    MemLongPtr(vTblMeowPtr) = VBA.Int(AddressOf Moew)
    '
    c.Meow 'Prints "Meow in .bas" to the Immediate Window
    '
    'Revert the original address
    MemLongPtr(vTblMeowPtr) = originalMeow
    '
    c.Meow 'Prints "Meow" to the Immediate Window
End Sub

Public Function Moew(ByVal this As Class1) As Long
    Debug.Print "Meow in .bas"
End Function
```

I've used [LibMemory](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-MemoryTools/blob/master/Code%20Modules/LibMemory.bas) for the memory manipulation.

If you change the `Meow` class method to a `Function` instead of a `Sub` then you need to have an extra `ByRef` paramater at the end of the parameters list within the `Meow` method in the .bas module.

**EDIT #1**

I thought of the issue discussed in the comments below and the only reason I could come up with was that the IDispatch only works with a pointer to the IUnknown interface.

This means that:

> ```
> Public Function Meow(ByRef this As Class1) As Long
> ```

will crash the Application

But, this works:

```
Public Function Moew(ByVal this As Class1) As Long
    Debug.Print "Meow in .bas"
End Function
```

because passing `ByVal` forces a QueryInterface and an AddRef on the IUnknown (with Release when exiting scope)

This also works:

```
Public Function Moew(ByRef this As IUnknown) As Long
    Debug.Print "Meow in .bas"
End Function
```

**EDIT #2**

Apologies for making another edit.

The Invoke method is not working with a pointer to IUnknown. It is working with a pointer to IDispatch. This can be checked with:

```
Public Function Moew(ByVal this As LongPtr) As Long
    Debug.Print this
    Debug.Print "Meow in .bas"
End Function
```

which will print the ptr to the IDispatch interface. So, why does `ByRef this As Class1` fail? And why do `ByVal this As Class1` and `ByRef this As IUnknown` work?

`ByRef this As Class1`
I believe the VarPtr(this) address is not accessible to VB, hence we are reading memory that we should not. It's not like there is an extra AddRef or Release on the IUnknown interface because the method never gets called using this declaration. The Application simply crashes when Invoke is trying to call the method.

`ByVal this As Class1`
The method simply creates a VB variable (on VB memory space) and calls AddRef

`ByRef this As IUnknown`
As this is not a dual interface, a call to QueryInterface and an AddRef is done. The memory address of 'this' is on local memory space, same as in the second example.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! One question; you use ByVal this rather than ByRef; is that a typo? And have you had luck calling any methods or properties of `this`?

Comment: Apologies. I did not even realize. I did it out of habit. A long time ago, while hooking IUnknown::Release, I discovered that when a non-VB function calls a VB one it is better to have the instance parameter passed ```ByVal``` to avoid crashes. I will think of an explanation and if I come up with a decent one, I will edit the answer accordingly. Yes, using the code in the answer allows me to access all methods of the class within the ```Meow``` method of the .bas module. Raising errors also works properly.

Comment: @Greedo Edited the answer, hope I am correct in my assumption. BTW, you always seem to ask the correct questions. Excellent job!

Comment: @Greedo I've done another edit. Hope I got it right this time.

Comment: @Greedo Your question helped me with updating the logic in the [instance redirection](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/253233/private-vba-class-initializer-called-from-factory-2) logic (see Edit #1). Thank you for that! It seems that indeed the entry point to a class in early binding has some extra safety mechanisms as opposed to late binding.